# When using a UINavigationController the viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear methods of my controller are not called

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Here is the pitch.

- I have a UIViewController subclass which does something in its viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear methods.
- I want to nest this view controller in a UINavigationViewController.
- Depending on the view hierarchy complexity the two methods `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` of my controller may not be called.

What should I do then to make sure these two methods are always called regardless of my view hierarchy?

Example of a "complex" view hierarchy:

```
UIViewController subclass containing a UITabBarController
     |_ Each tab containing a UINavigationViewController
         |_ Each UINavigationController controller containing a custom UIViewController
```

When you present the TabBarController as a modal view the `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` methods of the TabBarController are called but not those of the custom UIViewControllers nested under the UINavigationViewControllers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**NOTE: this was written in 2013. Changes to the way iOS handles view hierarchies nowadays may render this solution useless and/or dangerous. So use at your own risk.**

**Original Answer**
When nesting a custom UIViewController under a UINavigationController the methods viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear of the custom viewController may not be called depending on the complexity of your view controller hierarchy (think modal views, navigation controller inside tab view controller...). So if you find yourself in this situation what can you do to ensure these two methods are called?

The answer...

### Use the UINavigationControllerDelegate methods

This is a very elegant method to implement for it does not rely on any assumptions regarding when the controller will be loaded by the navigation controller.

There are two methods available:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Here is how the code would change.

You need to declare that your CustomViewController implements the UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol:

```
@interface CustomViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

You need to set your CustomViewController as the delegate of the UINavigationController where you initialize it.

Last you must also add your custom implementation of the UINavigationControllerDelegate methods to your CustomViewController class implementation. For instance you can implement the `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` method so that:

- when the UINavigationController is about to show the view controller itself your viewWillAppear method is called
- when the UINavigationController is about to show another view controller the delegate of the UINavigationController is set to this other view controller, provided that this view controller implements the UINavigationViewControllerDelegate method.

List item

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([viewController isEqual:self]) {
            [viewController viewWillAppear:animated];
    } else if ([viewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UINavigationControllerDelegate)]){
            // Set the navigation controller delegate to the passed-in view controller and call the UINavigationViewControllerDelegate method on the new delegate.
            [navigationController setDelegate:(id<UINavigationControllerDelegate>)viewController];
            [[navigationController delegate] navigationController:navigationController willShowViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

And the `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:` can be implemented simply as follows:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
       didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
                    animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([viewController isEqual:self]) {
        [self viewDidAppear:animated];
    }
}
```

The benefit of this approach is really that you solely rely on the way the UINavigationViewController is supposed to work and you make your calls just at the right time. It also allows you to pass the delegation around as you move up and down the navigation controller hierarchy right before the viewWillAppear method is called.

Again for simple hierarchy this may not be required. But if you ever find yourself in a situation where your `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` methods are not called you now know what to do...

Comment: Do you have a source for this statement? I'm pretty sure I'm using viewWillAppear in this situation and it is being called. (will go and check now, though!)

Comment: @jrturton It's particularly the case when you start playing with modal view controllers and more complex hierarchy. And the solution remains generic: if your method is not called, use the UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol instead of direct calls

Comment: @jrturton I've made my statement a bit less strong to reflect the fact that if the methods are not called you can use the delegation technique instead of direct calls.

Comment: You had me worried there for a minute!

Comment: @jrturton sorry... I'm restating the problem and solution right now so as not to scare people like I scared you...

Comment: Am I to understand that a child view controller of a navigation controller acts as a delegate to it? This seems incredibly *not* ok, given the 1:1 nature of the delegate/delegator pattern...

Comment: Be careful using this solution.. from a quick play these delegate methods are called before the visible view controllers subviews are layed out whereas when using a UIViewController standalone viewWillAppear is called afterwards.

Comment: So what is the solution in iOS8?

Comment: in answer to my own question, it looks like viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear now are called on view controllers inside a UINavigationController in iOS8.

Comment: It's not a good idea to make a child of a container the delegate of the container, instead use the notifications @"UINavigationControllerWillShowViewControllerNotification", @"UINavigationControllerDidShowViewControllerNotification" instead.

Answer (score 8):

One reason this will happen is if you override `viewDidAppear:` in your `UINavigationController` subclass and don't call `[super viewDidAppear:animated];`...

Comment: That is exactly it. So many answers suggest to invoke the viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear manually from another containing controller. In my case, a closer look at these overrides was enough to see where I forgot to call the super implementation.

Answer (score 3):

It is 2015 now and you probably don't need to use the UINavigationControllerDelegate methods as in the accepted answer. Just check **carefully** your code if you have any typo or copy/paste error.

I ran into an issue lately that `viewDidAppear` is no longer called after some copy/paste. After reading @Yar's answer, I did a search on `viewDidAppear` in my code and found that `[super viewDidAppear:animated];` was mistakenly called in `viewWillAppear`:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   //...      ^^^ 
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // this is never called :(
}
```

Just share this finding here in case people run into same issue.

Answer (score 0):

it should be done as follows:

See (*1) edit

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    CustomViewController *controller = [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    [controller release];

    self.window.rootViewController = navController; //(*1)
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [navController release];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Ok. And does CustomViewController appear? If not try `CustomViewController *controller = [CustomViewController new];` instead of `CustomViewController *controller = [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`

Comment: Yep it appears fine... That's not the point of the question though. The controller always appear but when nested inside a UINavigationController the viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear methods are not called.

Comment: Oh ok. In that case I don't know I'm sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

The above solution not works for me. My case is the custom view controller nested under a complex UINavigationController not gets called viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear. Use below in custom view controller:

```
beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: animated)  // Tells a child controller its appearance is about to change. Do not invoke viewWillAppear(_:), viewWillDisappear(_:), viewDidAppear(_:), or viewDidDisappear(_:) directly.
endAppearanceTransition() // Tells a child controller its appearance has changed.
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was similar to this only.

CustomTabBarController -> CustomUINavigationController -> RootViewcontroller

viewWillAppear of CustomUINavigationController and RootViewController are not getting called unless you switched to another tab and come back.

The solution is call super.viewWillAppear(animated: true)

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    **super.viewWillAppear(true)**
}
```

I struggled for more than a day for this small mistake.