# Is there a way to see if a vue is being displayed again after popViewController is called

Tags: iphone

I have code in the `viewWillAppear` method to run before the screen will be displayed again.  This works fine if I call `popToRootViewController,` and then the view is brought up again.  But if one presses the back button and `popViewController` is called, the `viewWillAppear` never gets called.

Is there a method that gets called when the view appears from `popViewController` being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, `viewWillAppear` is called when the Back button is hit.  You might try a Clean in Xcode and reset your simulator; sometimes that can lead to problems like this.  If you have a complex modal view structure, there are apparently cases where viewWillAppear is NOT called. You can use UINavigationControllerDelegate willShowViewController method to call ViewWillAppear;  see a complete answer and solution here:

[When using a UINavigationController the viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear methods of my controller are not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674958/when-using-a-uinavigationcontroller-the-viewwillappear-or-viewdidappear-methods)