# add UIToolBar in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm new to UIToolBar and want to add one to my swift project at the bottom. i've added a code which should work, but nothing i shows. How do i add a UIToolBar to my viewController programatically.

## ViewDidLoad

```
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 46, self.view.frame.size.width, 46)
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    toolbar.setItems(toolbarButtons, animated: true)
    toolbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(toolbar)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I had a similar problem, but it wasn't due to my code. Your code works as well. The issue most likely lies with where you are running that code. Make sure it is in viewDidLoad() or a similar view lifecycle function. Put a breakpoint in the function, and when you run your app, see if it hits it. If it doesn't hit it, you may have a problem similar to the one described in this post ([When using a UINavigationController the viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear methods of my controller are not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674958/when-using-a-uinavigationcontroller-the-viewwillappear-or-viewdidappear-methods))